# TSQL how to merge two Json arrays

Tags: json, t-sql

How to merge new array elements into an existing Json property?
Our two json objects look like this and we want to append the items of the 2nd json object to the 1st json object. (See desired result)

Is there a way to achieve this with JSON_MODIFY?
The microsoft documentation doesn't really show any example of multiple elements being merged into the already existing array. Only a single element. But we have a list of multiple elements that need to be merged.

**Edit:**
JSON_MODIFY(@json1, 'append $.Items', JSON_QUERY(@json2)) seems to create new array brackets instead of merging the items into the array.

Json Object 1:

```
DECLARE @json1 NVARCHAR(MAX) = '{
    "id": 1,
    "Items": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name" : "Item #1"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name" : "Item #2"
        }
    ]
}'
```

Json Object 2:

```
DECLARE @json2 NVARCHAR(MAX)='{
    "Items": [
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Item #3"
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "Item #4"
        }
    ]
}'
```

Desired Result:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "Items": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Item #1"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Item #2"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Item #3"
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "Item #4"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: In JSON, an array is ordered by construction. From your data, it seems that you don't exactly need to "append". Is that right? That would simplify answers.

Answer (score 3):

It's Cumbersome but possible to achieve with SQL Server's built it JSON support.

First, set proper sample data (**Please** save us this step in your future questions):

```
DECLARE @Json1 nvarchar(max) = 
'{
    "id": 1,
    "Items": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name" : "Item #1"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name" : "Item #2"
        }
    ]
}',

@Json2 nvarchar(max) = 
'{
    "Items": [
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Item #3"
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "Item #4"
        }
    ]
}';
```

Then, wrap a `union all` query containing [`openjson`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and [`json_query`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-query-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) for each one of the variables with a common table expression:

```
With cteArray as
(
    SELECT *
    FROM OPENJSON(JSON_QUERY(@Json1, '$.Items'))
    WITH(
        Id int '$.id',
        Name varchar(100) '$.name'
    )
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT *
    FROM OPENJSON(JSON_QUERY(@Json2, '$.Items'))
    WITH(
        Id int '$.id',
        Name varchar(100) '$.name'
    )
)
```

The result of that union all query is this:

```
Id      Name
1       Item #1
2       Item #2
3       Item #3
4       Item #4
```

Then, select the `id` from the first json using [`json_value`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), and add a subquery to select everything from the cte with [`for json path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-for-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#for-json). Add another `for json path` and specify [`without_array_wrapper`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/remove-square-brackets-from-json-without-array-wrapper-option?view=sql-server-2017) to the outer query:

```
SELECT JSON_VALUE(@Json1, '$.id') As id,
        (
            SELECT * 
            FROM cteArray
            FOR JSON PATH
        ) as Items
FOR JSON PATH,
WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
```

The final result:

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "Items": [{
            "Id": 1,
            "Name": "Item #1"
        }, {
            "Id": 2,
            "Name": "Item #2"
        }, {
            "Id": 3,
            "Name": "Item #3"
        }, {
            "Id": 4,
            "Name": "Item #4"
        }
    ]
}
```

You can see a live demo on [<kbd>Db<>Fiddle</kbd>](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=94b811c4bf50a29d93664d5cab7a120a)

Comment: Hm sadly it isn't just a simple json_modify call.
We have several items with different properties that need to be merged into the array but we'll see what we can do with this example. Thanks

Comment: No, json support in SQL Server is quite basic, I'm afraid. for anything other than obvious, straight-forward simple operations, you have to write (relatively) a lot of code.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem can be solved by

```
SELECT  dbo.udf_native_json_merge(@json1,@json2,null)
```

We faced similar issues trying to merge JSONs in MS SQL. We also wanted it to be recursive and allow us to define a strategy for arrays like "union", "concat" and "replace".

Our solution for JSON manipulations like merge, JSON path expressions and more is open source and available @ [Github](https://github.com/anyvado/sql)

Feel free to use, comment and contribute so we can further improve JSON methods for MS SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Not pretty but this will merge text and object elements.   I'm sure it isn't bullet proof.  Offered only as a potential solution.

```
Declare @json1 nvarchar(max) = '{"id":1,"messages":[{"type":"Info","text":"message1"},{"type":"Info","text":"message2"}]}'
Declare @json2 nvarchar(max) = '{"id":1,"messages":["justPlanText",{"type":"Info","text":"message3"},{"type":"Info","text":"message4"}]}'

select @json1 = case 
                when isjson(m.value) = 1 then
                  json_modify(@json1,'append $.messages',json_query(m.value))
                else 
                  json_modify(@json1,'append $.messages',m.value)
                end
from openjson(json_query(@json2,'$.messages')) m

select @json1
```

Results for @json1:

```
{"id":1,"messages":[{"type":"Info","text":"message1"},{"type":"Info","text":"message2"},"justPlanText",{"type":"Info","text":"message3"},{"type":"Info","text":"message4"}]}
```

Comment: The idea looks promising; however I think your answer would be easier to apply for the original poster if you copied the structure of the json from the question.